# Getting details selected images in php

Tags: php, html, performance, multi-upload

I'm using html5 js [to upload multiple images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). Why when we upload multiple images does the result (PHP: `print_r($_FILES['upimg']['name'])`) only shows details of the last selected image?

For Example:(i selected following image name)

> 111111.gif
>
> 222222.gif
>
> 333333.gif

PHP code only last selected image show: `333333.gif`

But I want to show details from all the images.

What do I do?

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/16abeG

FULL CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php
if($_FILES){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_FILES['upimg']['name']);
    
        //for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['name']); $i++){
            //if ($_FILES['error'][$i] == 0) {
                ////do your stuff here, each image is at $_FILES['tmp_name'][$i]
            //}
        //}
    }
?>
  <title>file input click() demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function doClick() {
      var el = document.getElementById("fileElem");
      if (el) {
        el.click();
      }
    }
    function handleFiles(files) {
      var d = document.getElementById("fileList");
      if (!files.length) {
        d.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
      } else {
        var list = document.createElement("ul");
        d.appendChild(list);
        for (var i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          list.appendChild(li);
          
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);;
          img.height = 60;
          img.onload = function() {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
          }
          li.appendChild(img);
          
          var info = document.createElement("span");
          info.innerHTML = files[i].name + ": " + files[i].size + " bytes";
          li.appendChild(info);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is a demo of calling <code>click()</code> on a form's file picker.
  Note that the file input element is actually hidden here, so the
  user doesn't have to see the path to the selected file.</p>
      <a href="javascript:doClick()">Select some files</a>
  <div id="fileList">
    <p>No files selected!</p>
  </div>
  <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upimg[]" type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
        <input type="submit" value="Click to see the result">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic i think is wrong you use HTML 5, but not upload images via AJAX you use form for this method.

Miltiple is only HTML 5 and you can't use for PHP purpose without AJAX.

I created similar plugin you can check : https://github.com/dimitardanailov/js-control-files-uploader

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a for loop somewhat like the code you have commented out....

```
if(isset($_FILES["upimg"]["name"])) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES["upimg"]["name"]);$i++) {
        echo $_FILES["upimg"]["name"][$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong, that code works for me however I am using AJAX like @d.danailov described

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use 
 tag before any of the .parent div?

for width ratio you of course can do it using jquery.

```
myElement.width = (parentElement.width/100)*40
```